# Netsuite - How to populate sublist based on item & location search

Tags: javascript, netsuite, sublist, suitescript, clientscript

So I'm trying to create a custom Reallocate Items Page with the main difference is the data in the Expected Ship Date. What I want to do is, to populate the sub-list based on what is in the Item ID and Location. Just like how the Standard Reallocate Items work.

So far I have created a the ff js as a Suit let for the page.

```
    var form = nlapiCreateForm('Reallocate Items');
    nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'DEBUG', form);

    form.setScript('customscriptcust_reallocate_field_change');
    var item = form.addField('item','select', 'Item','item');
    var location = form.addField('location','select', 'Location','location');
    var qtyonhand = form.addField('qtyonhand','float', 'Quantity On Hand');
    qtyonhand.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var qtycommitted = form.addField('qtycommitted','text', 'Quantity Committed');
    qtycommitted.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var qtyrequired = form.addField('qtyrequired','text', 'Quantity Required');
    qtyrequired.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var qtypicked = form.addField('qtypicked','currency', 'Quantity Picked');
    qtypicked.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var units = form.addField('unitofmeasure','select', 'Units','unitstype');
    units.setDisplayType('disabled');

    var sublist = form.addSubList('sublist','list', '')
    var checkbox = sublist.addField('checkbox', 'checkbox', 'Allocate');
    var orddate = sublist.addField('orderdate', 'date', 'Order Date');
    orddate.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var expshipdate = sublist.addField('cust_tl_expectedshipdate', 'date', 'Custom Expected Ship Date');
    expshipdate.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var custreqdate = sublist.addField('custreqdate', 'date', 'Customer Request Date');
    custreqdate.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var ordernumber = sublist.addField('ordernumber', 'text', 'Order No.');
    ordernumber.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var specialorder = sublist.addField('specialorder', 'text', 'Special Order');
    specialorder.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var customer = sublist.addField('customer', 'select', 'Customer','customer');
    customer.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var qtyord = sublist.addField('qtyord', 'float', 'Quantity Ordered');
    qtyord.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var qtyremaining = sublist.addField('qtyremaining', 'float', 'Quantity Remaining');
    qtyremaining.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var commit = sublist.addField('commit', 'text', 'Commit');
    commit.setDisplayType('disabled');
    var qrtcommitted = sublist.addField('qtycommitted', 'float', 'Quantity Committed');

    form.addSubmitButton('Submit');
    form.addResetButton('Reset');


    response.writePage( form );
```

And here is my Client Script.

```
if ((name === 'item' || name === 'location') && !isEmpty(nlapiGetFieldValue("item")) && !isEmpty(nlapiGetFieldValue("location"))){

  var item = nlapiGetFieldValue('item');
  var unitstype = nlapiLookupField('item',item,'unitstype');
  nlapiSetFieldValue('unitofmeasure',unitstype);
  var location = nlapiGetFieldValue('location');

  var filters = new Array();
  filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter( 'inventorylocation', null, 'anyof', location );
  filters[1] = new nlobjSearchFilter('internalid', null, 'anyof', item);
  var columns = new Array();
  columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('locationquantitycommitted');
  columns[1] = new nlobjSearchColumn('locationquantityonhand');
  var search = nlapiSearchRecord( 'item', null, filters, columns );

  if (search){
    var searchrow = search[0];
    var quantitycommitted = searchrow.getValue( 'locationquantitycommitted' );
    var quantityonhand = searchrow.getValue( 'locationquantityonhand' );
    //var quantitypicked = searchrow.getValue( 'quantitypicked' );
    nlapiSetFieldValue('qtycommitted',quantitycommitted);
    nlapiSetFieldValue('qtyonhand',quantityonhand);
    nlapiSetFieldValue('qtypicked', '100');
    }
  }
 }
```

My question is how do I populate the sub-list just like how it works in the Reallocate Items?
Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How do I populate the sublist when selecting a from the ID and Location just like in the Standard Reallocation Items Page?

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the `setLineItemValues` and `setLineItemValue` methods on your `nlobjSublist` reference.

If your sublist column IDs match up exactly with the IDs of the columns in your search result, you can simply pass your search results array to `nlobjSublist.setLineItemValues` to populate the entire list with your search results. Only the sublist columns that match exactly the search columns will be populated.

Failing that, you can iterate over your search results and use `nlobjSublist.setLineItemValue` to populate each row manually using each search result.

Comment: what should be inside the nlobgSearchColumn(),? each field in the sublist? If so, where can I find the Internal Ids?

Comment: Your search columns look fine; it's just the ID of the field you want from the search result.